# Multiple javascript promises .then and .catch hitting wrong catch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I think that I am not understanding something properly here as it's very strange behaviour. If I call queryFindPlayer it should be falling into the .then which it does if queryFindContract function is not there but when it is there like below it seems to fall to the queryFindPlayer catch and add a new player.

```
queryFindPlayer(models, ConsoleId, UserId, SeasonId, LeagueId).then(players => {
    const player = players[0];
    queryFindContract(db, player.Team.id, UserId, SeasonId, LeagueId).then(contracts => {
      console.log("player has a contract to a team");
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log("failed to find player");
    });
}).catch(e => {
  queryAddPlayer(models, UserId, TeamId).then(player => {
    console.log("added player");   
  }).catch(addPlayerError => {
    console.log("failed to add player, shouldn't happen");
  });          
});
```

Comment: You will have to show the code for `queryFindContract()` and `queryAddPlayer()`.  Also, you should likely be returning the nested promises from within the `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers.

Comment: FYI, it will go from `queryFindContract()` to the 2nd `.catch()` if `queryFindContract()` throws a synchronous exception or there's something else in the parameters that causes an exception or if `queryFindContract()` isn't returning a promise.  you can probably see EXACTLY what is going wrong by just placing `console.log(e)` at the start of both your `.catch()` handlers.  I pretty much ALWAYS log a rejection because you sometimes get unexpected rejections and you need to know what they are to see if they are programming errors rather than just data errors.

Comment: If it's going into the rejection handler (the fn you're passing `catch`), that means either A) `queryFindPlayer` is rejecting its promise, or B) An error is being thrown in your fulfillment handler (the fn you're passing `then` as its first arg). From your description, it sounds like `queryFindPlayer` is fulfilling its promise but that `players[0]` is `undefined`, so `player.Team` throws an error. It would seem very odd for a function called `queryFindPlayer` (singular) to return an array of players (plural). Fundamentally, you need to use the debugger to find out what's going on.

Comment: Side note: It seems odd to log "failed to find player" when you found the player, but didn't find their *contract*.

Comment: @jfriend00 okay then this is expected to happen, why wouldn't it drop into its own catch?

Comment: Some basic debugging to log each `.catch()` will probably tell you exactly what is going on here.

Comment: It won't go into its own `.catch()` if the error occurs before that `queryFindContract()` promise is created and returned.  Then, it will be an exception in the top level `.then()` which will cause flow to go to the top level `.catch()`.  Log your errors and all will be clear.

Answer (score 1):

If `queryfindPlayer()` resolves so you start execution of the `.then()` handler, but then you end up in the `queryFindPlayer().catch()` handler, that can occur for one of the following reasons:

1. If your code threw an exception before calling `queryFindContract()` such as if `const player = players[0]` threw an error of if `queryFindContract()` wasn't defined.
2. If your code threw an exception evaluating the arguments to pass `queryFindContract()` such as `player.Team.id` throws or any of the other variables you're passing don't exist.
3. If `queryFindContract()` throws synchronously before it returns its promise.
4. If `queryFindContract()` doesn't return a promise and thus `queryfindContract().then()` would throw an exception.

All of these will cause a synchronous exception to be thrown in the `queryFindPlayer.then()` handler which will cause it to go to the `queryFindPlayer.catch()` handler.  It never gets to the  `queryFindContract().catch()` handler because `queryFindContract()` either never got to execute or because it never got to finish and return its promise.

---

You can most likely see exactly what is causing your situation by just adding

```
console.log(e)
```

at the start of both `.catch()` handlers.  For clarity, also add a descriptive string before the `e`.  such as:

```
console.log("qfc", e);
```

and

```
console.log("qfp", e);
```

I pretty much always log rejections, even if expecting them sometimes because you can also get rejections for unexpected reasons such as programming errors and you want to be able to see those immediately and not get confused by them.

Comment: @jwoodw - If this helped you solve your problem, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I was not using the exception handler how intended.

```
queryGetContractById(models, id).then(c => {
  return queryFindPlayer(models, ConsoleId, UserId, SeasonId, LeagueId).then(players => {
    if(players.length != 0) {
      return queryFindContract(models, players[0].Team.id, UserId, SeasonId, LeagueId).then(contracts => {
        if(contracts.length != 0) {
          console.log("player has a contract to a team");
        } else {
          queryUpdatePlayersTeam(models, players[0].id, TeamId);
        }
      });
    } else {
      return queryAddPlayer(models, UserId, TeamId).then(player => {
        console.log("added player");   
      });
    }
  });
}).catch(e => {
  console.log("failed", e);   
});
```

In my promise, I rejected if there was no data returned and resolving if there was. I can see how this was wrong and I think this is now right.